# Google Spreadsheet - now() function update with web embedded link only

Tags: timer, google-apps-script, triggers, embed, spreadsheet

I'm running a spreadsheet which is using a now() function for a countdown delta.

**I want the embedded spreadsheet on my webpage to update the now() function whithout accessing the spreadsheet.**

The time triggers that I tried always require a user to load or edit the spreadsheet before it is updating. Even in "File/Settings" changing it to on change and every minute is not helping.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the add-on called "copyDown" ? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copydown/lipbbdpmkcbplmfnbholpabinnnkbbda?utm_source=permalink

Comment: Thanks. I looked into copyDown and don't see how it can be of any help as it is driven by Google forms and not trigger updating embedded documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the time trigger to update the cell?

```
function updateTime(){
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid).getSheets()[0].getRange('G10').setValue(new Date());
}
```

As Zig Mandel commented, a much simpler way would be to go into "Spreadsheet settings..." and change "Recalculation" to Every hour or minute.

Comment: Also in spreadsheet file properties i think there is a setting to autoupdate such function calls.